# UNREAL ENGINE 4 Cast Failed

Tags: анимация, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4, cast, blueprint

Когда я пытаюсь сделать cast to thirdperson character каст не срабатывает , как я предполагаю скорее всего  это происходит из-за try get pawn owner,  потому что когда вызываю функцию is valid из try  get pawn owner она возвращает is not valid.  Я пытался это  пофиксить cоздавал object reference  на моего  героя его  подсоединял к обьекту  cast to  thirdperson character .  из Меша героя вытягивал anim instance  подсоединял это к таргету try get pawn owner.  вместо  try get pawn owner пытался использовать  get character  player. Все безуспешно от  отчаянья я подумал может быть это происходит  из-за с++(герой на нем),  cоздавал новый класс на  Блупринтах и новый АнимБлупринт для него  ,но результат такой же .

Как пофиксить и сделать так  чтобы try get pawn ownere  был  Valid.
Картинка  ниже  показывает эту кашу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать Cast на вашего Character можно использовать get player controller, либо что-то связанное с get pawn, точнее сейчас не скажу